# Using Plotly create a heatmap; changing colors

Tags: r, plotly, heatmap

I'm new to R and Plotly, and I've been going crazy over this. I'm sure there's a simple solution I'm not understanding, but I haven't been able to find anything that I can follow to make it work.

All I want to do is change the color of this heat map to RdYlGn. As far as I know all I have to do is create a palette and change the colorscale. But my result every time is this:

[image]

My code below.

```
# Load libraries
library(plotly)
library(RColorBrewer)
# Load Dataframe
df <- data.frame(Overall_Assessment = c(3,2,2), 
    Budget_Equals_Estimate = c(3,2,4), 
    Risk_Assessment_Cost_Schedule_Technical = c(3,"",3),
    Crosschecks = c(5,1,1),
    Cost_Methodology = c(3,2,2),
    Schedule_Baseline = c(2,2,2),
    Engineering_Technical_Baseline = c(3,3,3),
    Requirements_Definition = c(5,5,5))
# Create Matrix
m <- matrix(df, nrow = 8, ncol = 3)

# plot matrix
confidencevalue <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

pal <- brewer.pal(5,"RdYlGn")

fig <- plot_ly(
    x = c("EMD", "O&S", "P&D"), 
    y = c("Overall Assessment", "Budget Equals Estimate", "Risk Assessment (Cost Schedule Technical)",
    "Crosschecks", "Cost & Methodology", "Schedule Baseline", "Engineering Technical Baseline", "Requirements Definition"),
    z = m, 
    colorscale = pal,
    type = "heatmap") %>% 
    layout(xaxis = list(side = "top"), 
    yaxis = list(categoryorder = "trace", title = "Confidence Enablers"), 
    margin = list(l=10, r=10, b=10, t=10))
fig
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?  I was stumbling through the brewer palettes and noticed that regardless of what `brewer.pal()` I tried, the colors on the chart were always the same incorrect colors.

Looking at `?plot_ly` help text for 'colors', it says "either a **colorbrewer2.org palette name** or *vector of colors in hexidicmal*..."  So I tried:

```
fig <- plot_ly(
    x = c("EMD", "O&S", "P&D"), 
    y = c("Overall Assessment", "Budget Equals Estimate", "Risk Assessment (Cost Schedule Technical)",
    "Crosschecks", "Cost & Methodology", "Schedule Baseline", "Engineering Technical Baseline", "Requirements Definition"),
    z = m, 
    colorscale = "YlOrRd",
    type = "heatmap") %>% 
    layout(xaxis = list(side = "top"), 
    yaxis = list(categoryorder = "trace", title = "Confidence Enablers"), 
    margin = list(l=10, r=10, b=10, t=10))
```

Produces:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the ingrained plotly colorscales are appropriate for what I need. In reality, I'm surprised that a red, yellow, green color scheme isn't already apart of the package.

Comment: Oops, I didn't realize I had strayed from your desired colorscale. Apologies.  I did find a list of valid plotly colorscales here: https://community.plot.ly/t/what-colorscales-are-available-in-plotly-and-which-are-the-default/2079

Comment: Oh, boy. It looks like R has been left behind with its list of ingrained colorscales. Python has the one I need. Just another incentive to switch over.

AFAIK, there is supposed to be a means in R plotly to create your own. But I can't get the hexidicmal to work with this kind of chart. It's so strange.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `colorscale` you can use the `colors` argument with `colorRamp`:

```
pal <- brewer.pal(5,"RdYlGn")

fig <- plot_ly(
    x = c("EMD", "O&S", "P&D"), 
    y = c("Overall Assessment", "Budget Equals Estimate", "Risk Assessment (Cost Schedule Technical)",
    "Crosschecks", "Cost & Methodology", "Schedule Baseline", "Engineering Technical Baseline", "Requirements Definition"),
    z = m, 
    colors = colorRamp(pal),
    type = "heatmap") %>% 
    layout(xaxis = list(side = "top"), 
    yaxis = list(categoryorder = "trace", title = "Confidence Enablers"), 
    margin = list(l=10, r=10, b=10, t=10))
```

[reference](https://plot.ly/r/heatmaps/#custom-colorscales)